# Как выровнять float элементы

Tags: css, float

Добрый день, начал изучать верстку и вот столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно выровнять элементы в шапке по центру по вертикали, но загвоздка в том что одна группа элементов имеет свойство float:left. Сначала я не понял в чем проблема, затем нашел одну из обучающих статей, где пишется что к float - vertical-align не применяется. Теперь я не знаю что делать. На картинке отображено что мне нужно сделать.
[image: что мне нужно сделать]

```
Мой код: https://codepen.io/chegonenko/pen/dpLJQb
```

Comment: Попробуй с line-height что-то сделать...

Comment: http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/ozOpWV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы прочитали верно, но это не относится к вашему примеру.
В вашем случае свойства `float` влияет только на элементы `.l_part`, `.l_part`, но не на их содержимое. Вам нужно лишь выровнять внутренности этих блоков. А так как все внутренние блоки у вас со свойствами `inline-block`, то они могут быть выровнены между собой.

1. Всем внутренним `inline-block`'ам задаем `vertical-align: middle`, чтобы они выровнялись между собой попарно. (`.picture`, `.l_text`, `.r_text`, `.phone`)
2. Для картинки задаем свойство `display: block`, чтобы она под собой не добавляла пустое пространство, что испортит выравнивание(читайте об этом отдельно, [например здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/space-under-img))
3. Внутрь заголовка `.header` после зафлоченых элементов - то есть в конец в вашем случае добавляем `<div>` со свойством `clear: both`, чтобы очистить обтекания. (что это и зачем это нужно делать читайте отдельно, [например здесь](http://www.css-tricks.ru/articles/details/AllAboutFloats))